Unable to move Project Folder in QGIS
I have a project folder containing the project .qgz and all the associated datasources. QGIS 3.34.4. Have ProjectProperties>SavePaths set to 'relative.' Would like to move that project folder to a different folder on my Mac(OS 14.5) eg from my Desktop Folder to my Documents Folder or to my local Dropbox Folder. Whenever I do and open, I get 'Handle Unavailable Layers' window that lists all my layers where source is on my laptop (vector ogr). Autofind no help. I 'Keep Unavailable Layers'. Open the changeDataSource plug-in, and all the paths look correct (triple-checked; truncated examples below), tried several replaces-all red when Apply. Reset to original (that still looks all correct). Close plug-in and still have no sources available for ogr layers (triangle !). Move the same project folder back to my Desktop and all works fine.
Examples: First works fine when project folder in my Desktop Folder. Second has layer source unavailable when project folder in my Documents folder (not in any subfolder or hidden folder).
/Users/Pete/Desktop/BLT MASTER QGIS/13_Kaczynski Easm Line.gpkg|layername=13_Kaczynski Easm Line
/Users/Pete/Documents/BLT MASTER QGIS/13_Kaczynski Easm Line.gpkg|layername=13_Kaczynski Easm Line

It's not an answer to your question but as a workaround does using the QPackage plugin move your project successfully?
